# Implement multiprocessing to test two videos simultaneously in opencv for object detection

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, pytorch, multiprocessing

I am implementing an object detection model using a YOLO algorithm with PyTorch and OpenCV. Running my model on a single video works fine. But whenever I am trying to use multiprocessing for testing more videos at once it is freezing. Can you please explain what is wrong with this code ??

```
import torch
import cv2
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='runs/best.pt', force_reload=True)

def detectObject(video,name):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    while cap.isOpened():
        pTime = time.time()
        ret, img = cap.read()
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = str(int(1 / (cTime - pTime)))
        if img is None:
            break
        else:
            results = model(img)
            labels = results.xyxyn[0][:, -1].cpu().numpy()
            cord = results.xyxyn[0][:, :-1].cpu().numpy()
            n = len(labels)
            x_shape, y_shape = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]
            for i in range(n):
                row = cord[i]
                # If score is less than 0.3 we avoid making a prediction.
                if row[4] < 0.3:
                    continue
                x1 = int(row[0] * x_shape)
                y1 = int(row[1] * y_shape)
                x2 = int(row[2] * x_shape)
                y2 = int(row[3] * y_shape)
                bgr = (0, 255, 0)  # color of the box
                classes = model.names  # Get the name of label index
                label_font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX  # Font for the label.
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), bgr, 2)  # Plot the boxes
                cv2.putText(img, classes[int(labels[i])], (x1, y1), label_font, 2, bgr, 2)
                cv2.putText(img, f'FPS={fps}', (8, 70), label_font, 3, (100, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        img = cv2.resize(img, (700, 700))
        cv2.imshow(name, img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()

Videos = ['../Dataset/Test1.mp4','../Dataset/Test2.mp4']
for i in Videos:
    process = Process(target=detectObject, args=(i, str(i)))
    process.start()
```

Every time I run that code it freezes.
Here is the output :

```
Downloading: "https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/archive/master.zip" to /home/com/.cache/torch/hub/master.zip
YOLOv5  2022-6-27 Python-3.9.9 torch-1.11.0+cu102 CPU

Fusing layers... 
YOLOv5s summary: 213 layers, 7023610 parameters, 0 gradients
Adding AutoShape...
```

Comment: Can you also share the path runs/best.pt as a drive link? I am trying to setup this code.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: @Aditya Here it is : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yTE0QVCzd4B8NMDI7sQVlg3hf4qxPv4V/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @furas I have tried this . For single video the code works fine. But after implementing multiprocessing it is freezing after results = model(img) line in my code.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I still don't see the runs.pt file in the google drive link you shared

Comment: in multiprocessing processes don't share memory - you may have to load model in every process separatelly. Eventually you may send model to process as another arugment but main process will save it in pickle files (for every process separated file) and other processes will read model from files - and this can take longer time.

Comment: @Aditya Go to that link it has best.pt file I used . You will not be able to see it directly in gdrive. click on download button it will download best.pt file locally which you can use .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by adding `torch multiprocessing` code.

```
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Process, set_start_method
try:
     set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
except RuntimeError:
    pass

videos = ['videos/video1.mp4', 'videos/video2.mp4']
for i in videos:
    process = Process(target=detectObject, args=(i, str(i)))
    process.start()
```

I was able to run on multiple videos at once this way.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still getting errors; try the below code: Good luck

```
import torch
import cv2
import time
# from multiprocessing import Process
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Process, set_start_method


model = torch.hub.load("yolov5", 'custom', path='best.pt', source='local', trust_repo=True, force_reload=True)

def detectObject(video,name):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    while cap.isOpened():
        pTime = time.time()
        ret, img = cap.read()
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = str(int(1 / (cTime - pTime)))
        if img is None:
            break
        else:
            results = model(img)
            labels = results.xyxyn[0][:, -1].cpu().numpy()
            cord = results.xyxyn[0][:, :-1].cpu().numpy()
            n = len(labels)
            x_shape, y_shape = img.shape[1], img.shape[0]
            for i in range(n):
                row = cord[i]
                # If score is less than 0.3 we avoid making a prediction.
                if row[4] < 0.3:
                    continue
                x1 = int(row[0] * x_shape)
                y1 = int(row[1] * y_shape)
                x2 = int(row[2] * x_shape)
                y2 = int(row[3] * y_shape)
                bgr = (0, 255, 0)  # color of the box
                classes = model.names  # Get the name of label index
                label_font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX  # Font for the label.
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), bgr, 2)  # Plot the boxes
                cv2.putText(img, classes[int(labels[i])], (x1, y1), label_font, 2, bgr, 2)
                cv2.putText(img, f'FPS={fps}', (8, 70), label_font, 3, (100, 255, 0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

        img = cv2.resize(img, (700, 700))
        cv2.imshow(name, img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()

try:
    set_start_method('spawn', force=True)
    videos = ['video/trx_l.mp4', 'video/trx_r.mp4']
    for i in videos:
        process = Process(target=detectObject, args=(i, str(i)))
        process.start()

except RuntimeError:
    pass
```